# Dynamic CSV Header Identifier using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to develop a python script using 3.11 that can identify the header values of a csv file given any format. By any format I mean that I am receiving csv files where the first row IS NOT always (very rarely) the 'true' header row. An assumption we can make is that the header row(s) will always contain at least one instance of the string 'date'. Right now I have the following formats that I am working with.

1. Single Line (row) headers:

- probably the most basic and straight forward format to work with. I completed this with the following snippet where I am reading the csv as a pandas dataframe. In the full script provided below I use a differnt method that is also working (....mostly)

```
def identify_header_single(df):
    #Single Line Header
    header_list = list(df.columns)
    print(header_list)
    return header_list
```

2. Multi-line Headers:

- These are csv files that have their "True" header values split across two or more consecutive rows within the CSV. Below is a screenshot of a file that I am currently working with (apologies for not sharing the column names as this information may be sensitive)
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5uQ4.png)

As you can see not every "True" header value is split across multiple rows. Header values can contain spaces, special characters, and occasionally numbers.

3. No headers:

- this is the case where there are no header values and the csv file only contains raw data. Pretty much ignorable, just report back with a message saying "There are no header values"

4. Any of the above scenarios where the 'true' header values are preceded by some sort of descript or meta data, ex: names, authors, companies, data export dates, etc. These preceding values typically are in the left most column and only contain one of the aforementioned values per row.
5. csv files that aren't ~really~ csv files.

- Ex: a .csv file that is only one column. Within the rows of this column each 'cell' or row contains data that is pipe '|' delimited that is meant to represent columns - this is a crazy format for me I'm not sure why data has been provided in this way but nonetheless here we are.

6. .txt and .xslx files:

- .xlsx files MAY have merged cells that either preceded the 'true' header values or the 'true' header values are contained within.

I believe I have already dealt with case #6 with a file conversion function as follows. It also deals with merged cells, however, I am not sure how to dynamically identify the range of merged cells here. This is necessary if the merged cells are not in the positions 'A1:I1' in the file, let's say 'A2:I2' would not be detected here.

```
def check_ext_and_convert(file_path):
    extension = file_path.split('.')[-1]
    extension = extension.lower()
    if extension == 'csv':
        return file_path
    if extension == 'xlsx':

        #Handle Merged Cells
        wb = op.load_workbook(file_path)
        ws = wb.active
        ws.unmerge_cells('A1:I1') # -> TODO: Need to find a way to dynamically detect megerd cells or cell ranges
        unmerged_file_path = file_path[:-5] + '_unmerged.xlsx'
        wb.save(unmerged_file_path)

        #Continue with file conversion
        df = pd.read_excel(unmerged_file_path)
        csv_path = file_path[:-5] + '_converted.csv'
        df.to_csv(csv_path, index = False)
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
        return csv_path

    elif extension == 'txt':
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path, delimiter='|')
        csv_path = file_path[:-4] + '_converted.csv'
        df.to_csv(csv_path, index=False)
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
        return csv_path
    else:
        print('Error: unsupported file extension')
    return csv_path
```

I was able to solve cases 1-4 (for the most part...see below code) with the following:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as op

def identify_header_multi_single_none(csv_file):
    # Open and read CSV file
    with open(csv_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        # Use reader -> returns a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given CSV file
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        header_rows = []
        for row in reader:
            # Check to see if the cell has only alphabetical symbols (no numerical values)
            if any(cell.isalpha() for cell in row):
                # Append cell value to header_rows[] list
                header_rows.append(row)
            # Check to see if the cell has only numerical symbols (no alpha values)
            elif all(cell.isdigit() for cell in row):
                #Continue with the script, do not append cell value to header_rows[] list
                continue
            else:
                break
    # If the length of the header_rows[] list is 0 than we have not found any header row values
    if len(header_rows) == 0:
        return None
    elif len(header_rows) == 1:
        return header_rows[0]
    #-------------TROUBLE BLOCK-------------
    else:
        header = []
        for i in range(len(header_rows[0])):
            col_header = ''
            for j in range(len(header_rows)):
                cell_value = header_rows[j][i].strip()
                if cell_value:
                    if col_header:
                        col_header += ' '
                    col_header += cell_value
            header.append(col_header)
        print(len(header_rows))
        print(len(header))
        df = pd.DataFrame(header)
        df = df.to_csv('header.csv')
        return header

def identify_header_special(csv_file):
    with open(csv_file, newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        # Initialize variables
        header_row = None
        max_non_empty = 0
        num_columns = None
        
        for row in reader:
            # Count number of non-empty or non-null values in row
            non_empty = sum(cell is not None and cell != '' for cell in row)
            # Set row with most non-empty or non-null values as header row
            if non_empty > max_non_empty:
                header_row = row
                max_non_empty = non_empty
            # Set header row values to nothing because there is no header row/no header row values, only CSV data.
            if any(cell.isdigit() for cell in header_row): 
                # print("There is no header row - only data within the file: " + csv_file)
                return None   
            # Set number of columns to match header row
            if num_columns is None:
                num_columns = len(row)
            else:
                num_columns = max(num_columns, len(row))

        return header_row[:num_columns] if header_row else []
    
    
def this_or_that_header_type(file):
    csv_file = check_ext_and_convert(file)
    header_multi_single_none = identify_header_multi_single_none(csv_file)
    # header_special = identify_header_special(csv_file)
    if header_multi_single_none != None:
        return header_multi_single_none
    if header_multi_single_none == None:
        return identify_header_special(csv_file)
    file.close()
```

This script works for uniquely formatted 5 files right now. However, I have 8 more test files that I am working with where one of them is also a Single Line header type file. This single line header type file reports the correct number of headers rows but for some reason is including the data row values as part of the reconstructed 'true' header values therefore pretty much giving me the whole file's data back as header values. I believe I have isolated this issue to the "Trouble Block" I marked in the code above.

If anyone has suggestions or knows of an existing script that may do this for me please share your knowledge! Thank you in advance for any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: I suspect it's not really possible to distinguish cases 1-3 without making some assumptions about either what the contents of your headers will be (e.g. "I expect to always have a column named Date") or some assumptions about what the contents of your data file will be. There's no way for us to know what the right assumptions are for your problem. If the data is so sensitive that you cannot say what the columns are named, then I'm guessing you don't want to share those assumptions.

Comment: @NickODell thanks for the quick comment! After looking back through the provided test files, there is actually always at least one instance of the string 'date' in the header row across all files. 

It can get a bit more complex when the true header row is multi line and we have two split header values with the string 'date' in different rows. 

Ex: 
Row 1: Open | Date
Row 2: Date | Closed